# I can't find an Ezra Bridger opening vid scene from Star Wars: Rebels

Tags: star-wars, episode-identification, star-wars-rebels

I vividly recall a scene from *Star Wars: Rebels* that I can't find any more. Was it removed?
It is a holovid of Ezra Bridger saying something along the lines if "I'm Ezra Bridger..."

It was a short scene that introduced Ezra and I recall it being played at the start of all the early season episodes. Going back now, I can't find it.

Does anyone else recall this scene or where it might be?

Comment: I don't remember the show having a "previously on" when I watched it

Comment: I think I remember this too, iirc it was a brief intro clip that would play before each episode when it originally aired on Disney XD. I remember it as kind of a hologram of Ezra saying something like "You passed the first test! Try to keep up" (possibly after saying something else). I've searched a lot for variants of "star wars rebels disney xd intro" or "star wars rebels try to keep up" but haven't had any success finding it so far.

Comment: Was it possibly from *Star Wars Rebels: Strike Missions* or some other *SW:Rebels*-based game?

Comment: @MiloP  Yes! Glad it's not just me.  I have searched everywhere and can't find it either. I remember watching that and thinking, something going to happen to Ezra.

Comment: @Lexible It was not. I've never played any Start Wars game.

Answer (score 5):

Found it!

I tried typing Disney XD rebels intro. Looked through a few choices and this one was about the fifth one in.